# What is the idiomatic way in go to write (by index) to an out of index element in a slice?

Tags: go, slice, allocation, indexoutofrangeexception

Suppose I have a sparsely populated slice and want to read/write to an element by index that may or may not be outside the capacity of the slice.

What is the idiomatic way of writing to s[x] when x may exceed the capacity?

Comment: A `map[int]` is probably a better choice than a sparsely-populated slice, for various reasons.

Comment: There are no sparse slices (or arrays) in Go. You must redesign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to check if `x` is outside the slice's range and extend the slice if it is (append zeros or something like that). There are no magic shortcuts. To "extend" a slice you can do:

```
a = append(a, make([]T, j)...)
```

Where `a` is the slice, `T` is the type of its contents and `j` is by how much you want to extend it.

Comment: I would probably make the new slice and copy the old into it. It's just as readable, and while the compiler _might_ recognize that the `make` in the `append` isn't needed, I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @JimB: Fair enough. For the record I took this snippet from https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#extend

Comment: Yeah, IMO some of those "tricks" try a little too hard to make on-liners. It's not incorrect, and probably makes no difference for small slices, but it's worth noting.